# Initialize a class level 2d string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class level 2d string array and I want to initialize it. Following is my code

```
public static  String[][] SBox ={
"63","7c"," 77" ,"7b", "f2", "6b", "6f" ,"c5" ,"30" ,"01", "67", "2b", "fe", "d7", "ab", "76",
"ca", "82", "c9", "7d", "fa", "59", "47", "f0" ,"ad" ,"d4" ,"a2", "af", "9c" ,"a4" ,"72" ,"c0" };
```

but it keeps returning the error : "String cannot be converted to String[]"

Comment: I do not think this is an exact duplicate of `Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array`. This question is asking about 2-d arrays with String values whereas that Question (and all its answers) deal with 2-d arrays of Integer values